# AngularJS, binding to a model in ng-repeat in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am trying to bind inside a directive (to access outside) to a model inside of an ng-repeat. So in the outer controller I have a variable I would like to bind in like

```
 //in the directive scope
 filterArray: '='
```

Inside the directive that would be bound inside the directive to a model in an ng-repeat like so -

```
 //inside the directive 
 <li ng-repeat="value in filter.values">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filterObject[filter.name][value]" ng-change="filterChange()">{{value}}
    </li>
```

This worked fine until I changed the directive to have an isolate scope, now it is saying cannot set property of undefined. Is there any way to get this working as intended? The idea is the variable would build out when the user clicks the inputs so the outer controller would be able to see the built object.

Apologies if this is a bit confusing - I have made a fiddle to clarify :   https://jsfiddle.net/vt1uasw7/42/  .

I want the outer controller to have access to the object built by binding the model - again this was working before I added the isolate scope. Thanks!

Edit: maybe the trick in this case is not to use the isolate scope? This one has me stumped, I've tried every combination of scope attributes :(.

Comment: the first thing I see in your fiddle is that your isolate scope has a property `filterArray` but you are referencing `filterObject` in your template (presumably the item in the outer scope).

Comment: @Claies Ah thanks for catching that. Even with it with the correct syntax it still has the same problem :(.

Comment: Are you sure that you only changed the scope of the directive without changing your model? The error you get is because you are trying to access an key in your filterObject/filterArray which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't pre-initialize your outter filterObject you can let the directive controller handle that for you:

```
$scope.filterArray[$scope.filter.name] = {};
```

And check your parameters as Claies stated, inside your directive you need to use filterArray and also the attribute name in the outter ng-repeat needs to be "filter-array and not "filterArray".

```
<div ng-repeat="filter in searchResults.filters" class="my-directive"  filter="filter" filter-change="filterChange" filter-array="filterObject"> </div>
```

See this https://jsfiddle.net/vt1uasw7/164/